# How to make an Exe Run as admin

Tags: installshield, runas, installshield-2009

I have a small application whose exe has to be worked in windows server 2008.
But in Win Server 2k8 it works properly only if the Option Run as administrator is selected, even if the user have admin previlege.

By selecting the property of that file to always run as admin, in the compatiblity tab will solve the issue.

But i have to enable this property while it installs.

And I am building the installer in Installshield 2009. 
My question is how to enable this property from the installsield.

How can I make the Exe alwas run as admin.

Any one pleeasse hellpp......

Thanks In Advance..

Jijesh.

Comment: This has been answered dozens of times.  You have to embed a manifest in the EXE.  How you do that depends on what the EXE is written in and has nothing to do with the installer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your exe always requires administrative privileges, you should build it with a manifest that specifies requireAdministrator. If it only requires administrative privileges sometimes, it should probably launch itself with ShellExecute using the verb "runas". In neither case should you rely on the shortcut option.